# Blackberry Webworks project not launching the blackberry simulator after building

Tags: cordova, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks

I am working on a project that compiles just fine without any errors in the console or error log. After the project build succeeds the blackberry simulator loads up as it should. However the project is not actually loaded into the simulator and placed in the downloads.

If I have the simulator open when the build succeeds, the simulator will display the loading circle icon in the middle of the screen but never perform any actions. I have tried cleaning the simulator and restarting my machine. But nothing works.
 I have tried the simulator on the Torch 9800 and the Bold 9700. I would assume run time errors would show somewhere in the console but yet nothing new is showing up there or in the command prompt screen. And if i run again any application then its showing alert wait, application is loading.

Any ideas as to what is going wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT

After looking into the build folder inside of the solution, the zipped folder is there however there is  StandardInstall or OTAInstall folder. The standard install folder contain the .alx .cod .cls and .cso files for the project.

Comment: So whats the problem? Is not launching a problem? Cant you go and launch it yourself?

Comment: Yes, Coder_sLaY.It not launching . Can you please tell me how can i launch simulator?

Comment: I would suggest download a sepearte simulator and launch it... Then manually install the cod files